# How to check the amount of shared memory allocated by a particular process in windows

Tags: windows, shared-memory, sysinternals

Tools like Process Explorer or AccessChk will tell you that shared memory exists in the segment section, but how to figure out how much memory was allocated by the particular named shared memory segment.

Answer (score 0):

VMMAP is another Sysinternals tool that can display detailed memory information for a process (including shared memory).